# How to request data from an isin instead of a ticker

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi, jbloomberg

Using the Bloomberg API via jBloomberg, how do I retrieve data based on an isin or a sedol code instead of a Bloomberg ticker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is detailed in the Bloomberg Developers Guide:

> A security must conform to the following syntax:
>
> ```
> /[Topic Prefix]/SYMBOLOGY[@Pricing Source][Exchange]
> ```
>
> Where [Topic Prefix] is one of the following: ticker cusip wpk isin buid
>   sedol1 sedol2 sicovam common bsid svm cins cats bbgid

So if you want to request data on IBM, you could use any of the following security identifiers:

```
String ticker = "IBM US Equity";
String isin = "/isin/US4592001014";
String sedol = "/sedol1/2005973";
```